# How to print taxonomy field in Drupal views-view-table.tpl

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I'm trying to figure out how to print a taxonomy term field in the Drupal 7 views-view-table.tpl file.

The scenario is that I have a content type called Song, and then a taxonomy vocabulary called Album. I have a view page called that displays all songs in a table and they are grouped by the album term. I've added custom fields to the album taxonomy so people can buy the album. I need to print those fields right above each table.

Hope that makes sense. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Is there one or several tables? "table" vs "each table". I am confused. Where do you want to print fields? Did you mean above each grouped songs? In that case it is not each table ...

Comment: Two tables. When it's grouped by the taxonomy term it outputs it as two separate tables.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason to print the taxonomy term fields in `views-view-table.tpl`? I understood that you want to print fields from the term.

I'd suggest you add a relationship to the view (to the taxonomy term) and add this way you can use all the term fields inside your view.